# Jquery row css problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Html Code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Jquery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('table tr:eq(0)').after('<tr><td>bla</td></tr>').css({'color':'red'});

});
```

ı need after append add css

```
<tr><td>bla</td></tr> >>> color red
```

How to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('<tr><td>bla</td></tr>').css({'color':'red'}).appendTo('table');
```

Comment: @Dennis more more Thank you Work

Answer (score 1):

You are adding css properties to your initial `<tr><td>test</td></tr>`, not the one you're creating.
If you want to modify the on you've just created, you need to remember it in some variable first:

```
var tr = $('<tr><td>bla</td></tr>');
$('table tr:eq(0)').after( tr );
tr.css( {color:"red"} );
```

Answer (score -1):

eq is a function mate. You can't use it inside the xpath string

you should go like `$('selectors').eq(index)`

Also .css is chained to the first selector. so it makes the first one red not what you are appending

```
$('tr').eq(0).after('<tr class="red"><td>bla</td></tr>');
```

and then your css is:

```
.red {color:red;}
```

Comment: @XGreen Not Work How to make ?
$('table tr').eq(0).after('<tr><td>bla</td></tr>').css({'color':'red'});